# Pass value of AngularJS variable to JSP directly or by intermediate JS variable

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jsp

I have an AngularJS nested dropdown menu in a .jsp web page:

```
<div ng-controller="AlgoController">
<select ng-model="myModel" ng-options="model.name group by model.shade for model in models"></select>
```

I can easily display the value of the selected menu item as follows:

```
{{myModel.swValue1}}
```

The problem is that I need to tell my JSP code what the value is, so that it can decide which Java code is going to be run.

I have been researching and experimenting and if this were a plain JS variable I could pass it into JSP like this:

```
<script>
var v = "I am the selected menu item";
</script>

<br><br><br>
<% 
    String st="<script>document.writeln(v)</script>";
    out.println("value="+st); 
%>
```

Someone said I could simply do something like this:

```
<script>
var v = $scope.myModel;
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
var v = myModel.name;
</script>
```

etc, but that just seems to leave `v` undefined.

My best attempt, which still doesn't work, is:

```
<script>
var scope = angular.element($("body")).scope();

var v = scope.myModel;
</script>

<br><br><br>
<% 
    String st="<script>document.writeln(v)</script>";
    out.println("value="+st); 
%>
```

I based my final attempt (above) on [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/y30wumrFNGzd3F3mRY92?p=preview) tangentially related Plunkr. However `angular` is undefined in my attempt and I can't figure out how `angular` ever worked in the example or what object name I could substitute in place of it (I tried everything).

I have the jQuery library loaded but I don't care one way or another if we use it.

**Update:**

I tried putting `id="mymenu"` in the `select` element and then doing this:

```
<script>
var v = window.document.getElementById("mymenu").selectedIndex;
document.writeln(v);
</script>
```

Which looks promising except that it always returns `-1`.  *Update: After spending an hour going down this path I no longer think the regular JavaScript `window` can receive values from Angular, though the opposite is possible -- same for document.getElementById in general.*

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS (javascript framework) runs on the browser while JSPs run on server where they are complied to HTML and sent back as response.

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) has a nice diagram that shows where JSPs reside.

If you want to send information to your JSP page then you can send a request to a its URL.

For example, if you want to get a list of name from your JSP, `xyz.jsp`, then send a request to the URL `http://<your domain>/xyz.jsp?operation=getnamelist`.

Where *operation* (it can be any name you want) is a GET request parameter.

In your case, you can send a request from your angularJS code to your JSP URL with the instruction about which JAVA code to run.